# Querying specific values within a "RECORD"

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I've been trying recently to query our Firebase Analytics data directly since the Firebase Dashboard only has some very basic data viewing capability.

It seems we can query the data directly in BigQuery, however it seems the type of database BigQuery uses is column based storage and has different data types than traditional databases like MySQL.

So I end up with the following task:

[image: the challenge]

I have tried to read some documentation on BigQuery's official documentation, such as here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays

But it seems it's about arrays, I don't really understand the documentation and in the BigQuery dashboard it says these columns are not actually an ARRAY, they are of type "RECORD":

[image]

.. for which I did not find much information online either.

So try to still query this since I don't really know how to go about it, I just tried something that probably will look stupid to you all hahaha:

```
SELECT *
FROM `diningcity-2ad82.analytics_171798853.events_20201222`
WHERE event_params.string_value.screen_name = "Deal details"
LIMIT 1000;
```

So I try to use the "." as a way to tell BigQuery "First go to event_params, then inside to string_value then to screen_name, to check final value".

But BigQuery doesn't like it:

```
Cannot access field string_value on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, ...>>> at [3:20]
```

So can someone help me find out what I'm doing wrong and what is the proper way to do this?

For reference I also tried going through this tutorial but also didn't really understand :

https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/JDBC_InstallGuide/content/jdbc/bq/features/records.htm

Answer (score 1):

What the BigQuery table format is saying is:

- `event_params` is an array of structs -- this is what "repeated" means.
- `value` is a struct inside that struct.
- `string_value` is a string field in that array.

I don't know why BigQuery uses "record" in the table description but "struct" everywhere else in the documentation.

To access arrays, use `unnest`.  One method is in the `FROM` clause.  As you have phrased the query, this would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM `diningcity-2ad82.analytics_171798853.events_20201222` e CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(e.event_params) ep 
WHERE v.screen_name = 'Deal details'
LIMIT 1000;
```

The only issue is that `screen_name` is probably the "key" value and not a column/field name.  So, you really want:

```
SELECT *
FROM `diningcity-2ad82.analytics_171798853.events_20201222` e CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(e.event_params) ep 
WHERE ep.key = 'screen_name' AND
      ep.value.string_value = 'Deal details'
LIMIT 1000;
```

If you don't want all the parameters in the result set, you can use:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT (event_params)
```

You can also do this in a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM `diningcity-2ad82.analytics_171798853.events_20201222` e         
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM UNNEST(e.event_params) ep 
              WHERE ep.key = 'screen_name' AND
                    ep.value.string_value = 'Deal details'
LIMIT 1000;
```

This is handy if you don't want to multiple the number of rows when a row could have more than one match.

Comment: Hi, so I've checked your answer, one thing that confuses me is that Kyrylo's answer that works in BigQuery is quite similar to yours, but with one key difference:
select * from diningcity-2ad82.analytics_171798853.events_20201222 as e, unnest(e.event_params) as ep WHERE ep.key = 'screen_name' AND ep.value.string_value = 'Deal details'; 
In your solution, you also CROSS JOIN "ep.value" instead of only event_params, may I ask what is the difference? Is there any?

Comment: Actually if I try your second code snippet, I get an error in BigQuery editor on the CROSS JOIN UNNEST(ep.value) AS v part: Values referenced in UNNEST must be arrays. UNNEST contains expression of type STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, ...> at [2:124]
It seems the ep.value part cannot be UNNESTED or whatever

Comment: According to the definition of the data, value is an array of strings within an array of records.

Comment: BigQuery seems to disagree with you 

Comment: @FlorianMonfort . . . I misread the data structure and updated the answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate the data that you have in the WITH clause of the query below. In order to access elements of array (REPEATED) you have to [UNNEST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays) them:

```
with data as (
select array<struct<value struct<string_value STRING, int_value INT64>, key STRING>>[struct(struct('1', 1), 'key1'), struct(struct('2', 2), 'key2')] as event_params
)
select unnested_array.value.string_value, unnested_array.value.int_value 
from data, unnest(data.event_params) as unnested_array;
```

Your `event_params` field is actually an `ARRAY` of `STRUCT`. It is of type `RECORD` and its mode is `REPEATED`, which are namings from legacy SQL and it is equal to `ARRAY` of `STRUCT`s. You can find a comparison of standard SQL and legacy SQL data types [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#type_differences).

You can see some examples of querying nested fields [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#querying_nested_arrays) in the documentation.

Comment: I used WITH clause to simulate the data you have in `diningcity-2ad82.analytics_171798853.events_20201222` just for the example of how you can query your data. You don't have to use WITH clause, rather use `diningcity-2ad82.analytics_171798853.events_20201222` instead of `data` in you FROM clause and then you'll have access to all the columns in the table you query. The important part is using `UNNEST(data.event_params)` which should be similar in your case. Let me know if it is not understandable, so I can provide a better answer

Comment: I tried:

SELECT *
FROM `diningcity-2ad82.analytics_171798853.events_20201222`, UNNEST(event_params)
WHERE event_params.string_value.screen_name = "Deal details"
LIMIT 1000;

Still get the same error, I don't get it

Comment: Try this please: select * from `diningcity-2ad82.analytics_171798853.events_20201222` as e, unnest(e.event_params) as ep WHERE ep.key = 'screen_name'  AND ep.value.string_value = 'Deal details';

Comment: I also don't understand what "WITH" does, I don't understand why do I need this? I want to select all the columns by doing SELECT * and just filter using WHERE

Comment: Find more about the `WITH` clause in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with_clause). If you use the query from my previous comment, then you don't need the `WITH` clause anymore. Originally, I used the `WITH` clause to simulate the behavior of your table...