# Filtering query by two values in same ARRAY or STRUCTs in Firebase Analytics BigQuery database

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

This question is a follow-up to this [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65421054/querying-specific-values-within-a-record).

In the previous example, we found how to filter an ARRAY of STRUCTs from Firebase's Analytics database.

Now here is the new challenge on top:

[image: What we are trying to do]

My thinking was, since we already did:

UNNEST(event_params) AS ep

This means that event_params is now flattened, so that means its values inside from the following ARRAYS:

- value.string_value: can access values;
- value.int_value: can access values;
- etc..

So my thinking goes, since I managed to access value.string_value = 'Restaurant profile', it should be no problem to also access the other value you can see in the example called "restaurant_id", so I add some more AND statements:

```
  ep.key = 'restaurant_id' AND
  ep.value.int_value = 2045881 AND
```

But as you can imagine since I'm posting about it, the result was not quite what was expected  even though technically BigQuery did accept my solution:

[image: Empty results]

Any idea what is wrong in my initial query and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea what is wrong in my initial query and how I can fix it?

The problem was is that `ep.key` cannot be at the same time both `firebase_screen` and `restaurant_id` - so instead of using `AND` you need to use `OR` as in below example

```
SELECT *
FROM `diningcity-2ad82.analytics_171798853.events_20201222` e, UNNEST(e.event_params) ep 
WHERE e.platform = 'IOS' AND (
    (ep.key = 'firebase_screen' AND ep.value.string_value = 'Restaurant profile') OR 
    (ep.key = 'restaurant_id' AND ep.value.int_value = 2045881)
  )
LIMIT 1000;
```

> But what if I need both these conditions to be true? ...

I think in this case your initial query is not the best start - try below instead

```
SELECT *
FROM `diningcity-2ad82.analytics_171798853.events_20201222` e
WHERE e.platform = 'IOS' AND (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM e.event_params 
  WHERE
    (key = 'firebase_screen' AND value.string_value = 'Restaurant profile') OR 
    (key = 'restaurant_id' AND value.int_value = 2045881)
  ) = 2
LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: But what if I need both these conditions to be true? if I use OR, then that means this parameter called restaurant_id which is used in other screens than 'Restaurant profile' will also be returned, which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM `diningcity-2ad82.analytics_171798853.events_20201222` e, 
      UNNEST(e.event_params) ep 
WHERE e.platform = 'IOS' 
  AND ep.key = 'firebase_screen'
  AND ep.value.string_value = 'Restaurant profile'
  And exists (select 1 from UNNEST(e.event_params) epp
               Where epp.key = 'restaurant_id' 
                 AND epp.value.int_value = 2045881)
LIMIT 1000;
```